# Spring MVC Form Tag - Radio button

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I've been trying to loop through an ArrayList of contractors and select one of them to be passed on to a Controller POST method.  I am getting nowhere.

The following gives the error shown in the 2nd block.  I think I am not dereferncing it properly.

I just need to pick out the loginId and pass it on to the controller.

```
<c:forEach items="${searchResults}" var="searchResult">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${searchResult.loginId}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${searchResult.email}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${searchResult.firstName}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${searchResult.lastName}" /></td>
        <td><form:radiobutton path="${searchResult.loginId}" value="${searchResult.loginId}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Error Message (sorry for the length).

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'BC2506E93E207D1AE040700ACA2479D7' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'BC2506E93E207D1AE040700ACA2479D7' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Comment: show your page, form object and controller. It seems you submit smth else not only loginId.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `path` is supposed to be the name of a property of the command oject associated with the form. In the case of a radiobutton tag, the radio button will be checked if the value in the property referenced by the path attribute has the same value as the value references by the `value` attribute.

So, if the command object has a `getFoo()/setFoo()` property, and if `getFoo()` returns "hello", and the `searchResult.getLoginId()` returns "hello", the following tag

```
<form:radiobutton path="foo" value="${searchResult.loginId}"/>
```

will generate the following checked HTML radio input:

```
<input type="radio" value="hello" checked="checked"/>
```

If `searchResult.getLoginId()` returns "goodbye", then the following tag

```
<form:radiobutton path="foo" value="${searchResult.loginId}"/>
```

will generate the following unselected HTML radio input:

```
<input type="radio" value="goodbye"/>
```